# Insert "HTTP Request Defaults" value dynamically

Tags: httprequest, jmeter

I am trying to Insert "HTTP Request Defaults" values dynamically from the command prompt so that I can run my tests against different servers. However, I can't find a place in the test GUI where I can enter `${__P(hostname,www.dummy.org)}`. Is it in the "Server name or IP" field or in the "Path" field?

In the [Apache user manual](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#using_variables), it says:

> For example, you might define the following on the Test Plan:
>   `HOST www.example.com`
>   `THREADS 10`
>   `LOOPS 20`
>
> You can refer to these in the test plan as `${HOST}` `${THREADS}` etc. If you later want to change the host, just change the value of the `HOST` variable. This works fine for small numbers of tests, but becomes tedious when testing lots of different combinations. One solution is to use a property to define the value of the variables, for example:
>   `HOST ${__P(host,www.example.com)}`
>   `THREADS ${__P(threads,10)}`
>   `LOOPS  ${__P(loops,20)}`
>   You can then change some or all of the values on the command-line as follows:
>   `jmeter ... -Jhost=www3.example.org -Jloops=13`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put it in : Server name or IP
But only the host name.

Path after hostname must be put in Path field